# Trying to get a timer to go off every minute on even intervals

Tags: java

I wont to write code that will have the timer go off every minute I want the time to be in even interval so the second value will be zero when the timer goes off.  Now i'm getting the current seconds. subtracting 60 from it so this is hpw many seconds until the first minute.  Then multiplying it by a 1000 and setting the timers inertial delay to that value.  Now when the timer call nbe goes off I got 58 for the seconds.  I ran the program again got 34, then ran it again and got 18

set up code

```
Calendar time=Calendar.getInstance();
int seconds=Calendar.SECOND;
seconds=60-seconds; // time until next minut

len=1000*60;
Timer timer = new Timer(len, this);
timer.setInitialDelay(1000*60+seconds*1000);

timer.start();
```

call back code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getID()==0)
    {
        int p;
        double d;
        p=t.daySize;
        String temp;

        Calendar firstTime2=Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("starting tme");
        temp=dateFormat.format(firstTime2.getTime());
        System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: Swing timers are not that accurate. You may consider making the Timer's time slices smaller, but only report the time when the Timer reaches the time of interest. So... checking the time every 2 or 5 seconds, adjusting the delta time, and reporting when it's on the minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what Timer class you're referring to above. The standard Java Timer class (java.util.Timer) would be used like this

```
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    public void run()
    {
      //your current ActionEvent
    }
}

Timer t = new Timer("My Timer");
t.schedule(tt, new Date(wheneverTheFirstOneIs), 1000*60);
```